# Auto increment feature in Database

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I use SQL Server and when I create a new table I make a specific field an auto increment
primary key. The problem is some people told me making the field an auto increment for the primary key means when deleting any record (they don't care about the auto increment field number) the field increases so at some point - if the type of my field is integer for example - the range of integer will be consumed totally and i will be in trouble. So they tell me not to use this feature any more.

The best solution is making this through the code by getting the max of my primary key then if the value does not exist the max will be `1` other wise `max + 1`.

Any suggestions about this problem? Can I use the auto increment feature?

I want also to know the cases which are not preferable to use auto increment ..and the alternatives...

note :: this question is general not specific to any DBMS , i wanna to know is this true also for DBMSs like ORACLE ,Mysql,INFORMIX,....

Thanks so much.

Comment: Well, what is the problem if there are "holes" in the PK numbers order? Who cares?

Comment: @Serkan - this is a phantom issue, see arguments below for why the issue does not exist.  `UniqueIdentifier` should certainly not be used with this as the motivation. It is a 16 byte value which will consume 4 times more space than an `int`, which is acceptable in vast majority of cases, and twice as much as a `bigint` which will almost always be acceptable, but usually not necessary

Comment: @AdamRalph - Did you not notice the smiley at the end of his answer.  He was making a joke.

Comment: @AdamRalph its just comment, NOT ANSWER. Im not serious :)

Comment: @Mystere Man - no I didn't notice... and if I didn't then perhaps others might not either - I'm all for jokes in the right place at the right time but this could easily send people off on the track - plenty of people seem to be very susceptible to the suggestion of GUIDs as identity values...

Comment: @AdamRalph, I am totally agree with you it is not right place to make a joke it is flow of knowledge and if this type of joke occurred than it would ultimately insulted of knowledge. as whole community as well as new comer could be misguided.

Comment: In my experience, a smiley `:)` normally means "I am happy". "I am joking" is normally signified by either a winkie `;)` or a tongue-in-cheek `:^)` .

Comment: The people who told you this are clearly uniformed and you should not trust their judgement or competence when it comes to database design on this or any other issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use identity (auto increment) columns. The [bigint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) data type can store values **up to 2^63-1** (9,223,372,036,854,775,807). I don't think your system is going to reach this value soon, even if you are inserting and deleting lots of records.

If you implement the method you propose properly, you will end up with a lot of **locking problems**. Otherwise, you will have to deal with exceptions thrown because of **constraint violation** (or even worse - **non-unique values**, if there is no primary key constraint).

Comment: +1. Also, don't forget, you will still have all those "holes" if going the max+1 route - that would only make a difference if you only delete the last record put in.

Comment: Race conditions means that if two requests for a new number come in at the same time both could be given the same number. This cannot happen using an identity but has to be carefully programmed to avoid in a manual process which is one of the main reasons why a manual process for getting id numbers is a poor idea.

Answer (score 9):

An `int` datatype in SQL Server can hold values from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.

If you seed your identity column with -2,147,483,648, e.g. `FooId identity(-2,147,483,648, 1)` then you have over 4 billion values to play with.

If you really think this is still not enough, you could use a `bigint`, which can hold values from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, but this almost guaranteed to be overkill. Even with large data volumes and/or a large number of transactions, you will probably either run out of disk space or exhaust the lifetime of your application before you exhaust the identity values when using an `int`, and almost certainly when using a `bigint`.

To summarise, you should use an identity column and you should not care about gaps in the values since a) you have enough candidate values and b) it's an abstract number with no logical meaning.

If you were to implement the solution you suggest, with the code deriving the next identity column, you would have to consider concurrency, since you will have to synchronise access to the current maximum identity value between two competing transactions. Indeed, you may end up introducing a significant performance degradation, since you will have to first read the max value, calculate and then insert (not to mention the extra work involved in synchronising concurrent transactions). If, however, you use an identity column, concurrency will be handled for you by the database engine.

Comment: is this the case in mysql and Informix DBMSs also ,, or not

Comment: abstract number - it's only purpose is to hold some kind of unique value - it has no other use, therefore, if the number sequence is 1, 3, 4, 5, 18, 19, 105, 108, 1006, 10020230 it doesn't matter since the numbers themselves have no meaning. the only consideration is whether enough values are available, which, as explained above, there are.

Comment: I think you mean "arbitrary" value, not "abstract"

Answer (score 4):

The solution they suggest can, and most likely will, create a concurrency problem and/or scalability problem.  If two sessions use the Max technique you describe at the same time, they can come up with the same number and then both try to add it at the same time.  This will create a constraint violation.

You can work around that problem by locking the table or catching exceptions, and keep re-inserting.. but that's a really bad way to do things.  Locking will reduce performance and cause scalability issues (and if you're planning as many records as to be worried about overflowing an int then you will need scalability).

Identity fields are atomic operations.  Two sessions cannot create the same identity field, so this problem is non-existent when using it.

If you're concerned that an identity field may overflow, then use a larger datatype, such as bigint.  You would be hard pressed to generate enough records to overflow that.

Now, there are valid reasons NOT to use an identity field, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Continue to use the identity feature with PK in SQL Server.  In mysql, there is also auto increment feature.  Don't worry that you run out of integer range, you will run out of hard disk space before that happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice AGAINST using the Identity/Auto-increment, because:

- It's implementation is broken in SQL server 2005/2008. [Read more](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value)
- It doesn't work well if you are going to use an ORM to map your database to objects. [Read more](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx)

I would advice you to use the Hi/Lo generator if you usually access your database through a program and don't depend on sending insert statements manually to the DB. You can read more about it in the second link.

Comment: That is another discussion :) But I don't really see that as a pitfall. The advantages outweigh that marginal drawback

Comment: yes i map all my tables to classes in the data access layer ,, is using auto increment in this case will be a big problem ..

Comment: Since Identities are the best, most reliable (in over 10 years I haven't run into that edge case) and fastest for performance of all the id possibilities, why on earth would you ever consider using an ORM that has trouble with them. That's just dumb. Also you may have records that are not added through the ORM but through data imports. It is contraindicated to rely on an ORM  process for this sort of thing for most business applications.